# Is it ok to change the EQUALITY on an attributetype in openldap

Tags: ldap, openldap, schema

I'd like to be able to do substring searches against a particular attribute which is defined in the schema as:

```
attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.25 NAME 'automountInformation'
        DESC 'Information used by the autofs automounter'
        EQUALITY caseExactIA5Match
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 SINGLE-VALUE )
```

Given that this is an external schema file, can I legitimately change the EQUALITY to caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch for instance? Will it affect data already in the directory? Any gotchas?

---

yes, take the point about case sensitivity. I was more concerned with being able to search for substrings.

In particular it is often useful to ask the question, "which automount maps are concerned with this file system?" At the moment - because it is not substring searchable - the only way to do it is to ask for the "automountinformation" and grep through it. I was looking for a more elegant solution.

Mainly I was concerned about whether it was even possible to change that attribute on a running directory. Would it have repercussions? would I have to reindex? etc. While I have long exposure to LDAP and LDIF, I have never tried to change the schema on a live directory...

Comment: Since the autofs daemon deals with filesystem paths and directory names and on *NIX filesystems those are typically case-sensitive;   at first glance that seems a bad idea. Typically deviating from RFC standards ([RFC 2307 draft 02](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-howard-rfc2307bis-01) in this case) is at your own peril

Comment: @HBruijn True, `caseExactIA5SubstringsMatch` is a more sensible EQUALITY candidate.